# Make sure chained tasks be executed by the same worker in multiple workers setup

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, video-processing, celery-task

I'm building a content moderation system by Python. When a video is uploaded to my system, I am using Celery to distribute this video to my Celery workers. These workers are on different machines. I created 3 tasks to do content moderation.

```py
@app.task(name="download_file", track_started=True)
def download_file(download_url, file_id):
    # Download the file

    return file_id
```

```py
@app.task(name="is_sfw", track_started=True)
def is_sfw(file_id: str) -> tuple[str, bool, float]:
    # Do checking if this video is sfw

    return file_id, is_sfw_result, score
```

```py
@app.task(name="moderate", track_started=True)
def moderate(file_id: str, download_url: str):
    download_task = download_file.s(download_url, file_id)
    is_sfw_task = is_sfw.s()

    chained = chain(download_task, is_sfw_task).apply_async()
    return chained
```

Based on the `moderate` task defined as the above, `download_file` task and `is_sfw` task must be executed on the same worker machine.
For example, I have 2 worker machines `W1` and `W2`. If `W1` receives `moderate` task, the chained tasks containing `download_file` and `is_sfw` must be executed on `W1`. Because `is_sfw` has an input that is the downloaded file from `download_file` task.
It is similar to the case that `W2` receives `moderate` task, `download_file` and `is_sfw` must be executed on `W2`.

I have searched around on the Internet but still not finding a solution. I cannot ensure chained tasks be executed by the same worker.
I very appreciate your help.